# Hard surface modeling issue

Tags: modeling

While trying to model the Mi8 HIP (Russian helicopter) I came into a few problems as the top view of the blueprint didn't seem to match inside sort of view as shown in the screenshot below, I'm not sure if its me that's making the mistake or the blueprint is incorrect. if anyone could tell me what I was doing wrong that would help a lot as this has had me confused for ages now. This question may not be entirely related to blender it is still related to modelling.
Thanks for the help :D
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see cross section number 8 like this :

[image]

The "turret" is seen in one side view and not in the other views but is there in cross-section 8.
I would use Google to find out what it is then you can decide if you need to have it in your modelor not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they match:
[image: Ми-8МТВ-5]
[Ми-8МТВ-5](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8-8#/media/File:Mi-8MTV-5_(2).jpg)

Look at the red star, then go up.